# Alias names for columns when using TOP N query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `user_bills`, containing 192 records, which I am sorting for every user with respect to their phone_number.  This query returns all columns in the table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM   user_bills 
WHERE  phone_number = 4423568989
```

... and the actual column names are as follows:

```
phone_number|user_name|reciept_number
```

However I would like them to be:

```
Phone Number|User Name|Reciept Number
```

I tried the query below, but I'm getting an error about missing keyword exist. Is there a better option?

```
SELECT TOP 1
FROM   (
          SELECT   phone_number 'Phone Number', 
                   user_name 'User Name',
                   usage_amount 'Usage Amount',
                   charges 'Charges', 
                   Fine, 
                   month_for 'Month',
                   Year,
                   Reciept
          FROM     user_bills 
       ) 
FROM   user_bills
WHERE  phone_number = 4423568989
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 phone_number 'Phone Number', 
             user_name 'User Name', 
             usage_amount 'Usage Amount', 
             charges 'Charges', 
             Fine, 
             month_for 'Month', 
             Year, 
             Reciept 
from user_bills 
where phone_number = 4423568989
```

Answer (score 0):

You're msiplacing the columns in the query.

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 phone_number "Phone Number" FROM user_bills WHERE phone_number = xxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place single quote around variable in WHERE condition.....

```
SELECT TOP 1
phone_number 'Phone Number', 
user_name 'User Name',
usage_amount 'Usage Amount',
charges 'Charges', 
Fine, 
month_for 'Month',
Year,
Reciept
FROM user_bills
WHERE phone_number ='4423568989'
```

Comment: That is not the OP's problem. That works. Look at his first select query